# Git exclude file not properly ignoring file

Tags: github

In my `/.git/info/exclude` file I have placed two directories and a file:

```
workspace
data
config.php
```

All of which are in the root. While 'workspace' and 'data' are being ignored, config.php is pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `config.php` from the git repo index first, if you want it to be ignored.

```
 git rm --cached config.php
```

(See for instance "[Making git “forget” about a file that *was* tracked but is now “`.gitignored`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/6309)")

Plus, ignoring directory should be specify with an '/' at the end of your line:

```
workspace/
data/
```